# Using python to solve transfer function outside of freqz format

Tags: python, signal-processing

I can't get the function into scipy freqz form so I tried to solve directly in python, but can't convert the complex to a float variable. Wrong implementation?

```
T = 1/(0.0001)
w_0 = m.pi/2
w = np.arange(-.005, .005, T)
j= 1j
h_num = 1-m.exp(j*w_0)-m.exp(-j*w_0)-2*m.exp(-j*w)+m.exp(-2*j*w)
h_den = 1-(0.9)*m.exp(j*w_0)-(0.9)*m.exp(-j*w_0)-(1.8)*m.exp(-j*w)+(0.81)*m.exp(-2*j*w)
mag = abs(h_num/h_den)
phase = np.angle(h_num)-np.angle(h_den)
```

Gives the following error:

> ```
> TypeError: can't convert complex to float on the exp(j*w_0)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the [`exp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.exp) function from the `math` module, which as stated in the [`math` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html)

> These functions cannot be used with complex numbers; use the functions of the same name from the cmath module if you require support for complex numbers.

So, as suggested you could use [`cmath.exp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html#cmath.exp) instead. This would take care of your current error arising during the evaluation of `exp(j*w0)`.

Unfortunately, with your posted code you will then get another error trying to compute the quantity `exp(j*w)` since `cmath.exp` does not support array arguments (neither does `math.exp` by the way). To resolve that second error you *could* create an array and evaluate the exponential on each array element, one at a time with a loop.
However, since you are already using `numpy`, it would just be a whole lot simpler to just use [`numpy.exp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html).

Also adjusting `T` and `w` computations to span the whole spectrum, you should get the following:

```
T = 0.0001
w_0 = np.pi/2
w = np.arange(-np.pi, np.pi, T)
j= 1j
h_num = 1-np.exp(j*w_0)-np.exp(-j*w_0)-2*np.exp(-j*w)+np.exp(-2*j*w)
h_den = 1-(0.9)*np.exp(j*w_0)-(0.9)*np.exp(-j*w_0)-(1.8)*np.exp(-j*w)+(0.81)*np.exp(-2*j*w)
mag = abs(h_num/h_den)
phase = np.angle(h_num)-np.angle(h_den)
```

As a side note, the corresponding computation with `scipy.freqz` would look like:

```
b = [1-np.exp(j*w_0)-np.exp(-j*w_0), -2, 1]
a = [1-0.9*np.exp(j*w_0)-0.9*np.exp(-j*w_0), -1.8, 0.81]
w, h = freqz(b, a, whole=True)
mag = abs(h)
phase = np.angle(h)
```